# LINQ to XML: how do I get only direct descendants of an XElement?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

```
Dim xml = <Root>
            <Parent id="1">
              <Child>Thomas</Child>
            </Parent>
            <Parent id="2">
              <Child>Tim</Child>
              <Child>Jamie</Child>
            </Parent>
          </Root>

Dim parents = xml.Elements
```

In this case, `children` includes all the Parent elements and all of the Child elements.  What's the best way to grab **only the direct descendants** of `<Root>`?

Should I write a LINQ query that selects elements where parent = `<Root>`?  Or is there some built-in method I'm missing that can get this for me?

**EDIT:** I had some confusion between `XElement.Elements` and `XElement.Descendants`.  As Ruben Bartelink pointed out, `XElement.Elements` will give me exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Can you edit in the actual incantation you ended up using? BTW please download LINQPAd and try it - its great for testing stuff like this. See examples at http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/LinqPad

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Exec summary - you want:

```
xml.Elements.Select(function(element) new XElement(element.Name,element.Attributes))
```

First answer:

> `XElement.Descendants`, or is it a trick question ? :P [There's an example of usage of Descendants here](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/zuker/archive/2009/01/11/linq-to-xml-xelement-descendants-vs-elements.aspx)

Revised answer, thanks Tormod -- something did feel wrong!:

Elements gives direct descendants, as you're looking for.  Descendants gives the full hierarchy [as you are alleging Elements does].  (The example I linked to makes this clear.  Apologies for the confusion!

So, finally, what you're looking for is (this time in VB):

```
Dim xml = <Root>
        <Parent id="1">
          <Child>Thomas</Child>
        </Parent>
        <Parent id="2">
          <Child>Tim</Child>
          <Child>Jamie</Child>
        </Parent>
      </Root>

REM All nodes two levels down in the hierarchy
Dim level2Nodes = xml.Elements.SelectMany(function(element) element.Elements)
level2Nodes.Dump

REM All Child nodes, no matter where they are:
Dim children = xml.Descendants("Child")
```

Each of which will yield you the 3 ``` elements for different reasons as covered in the REMs.

(Paste the above directly into [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) in VB statement mode)

I now see what might be confusing you - when you use Elements and look at it in a visualiser, you are still seeing the children:-

```
Dim parents = xml.Elements
```

If you only want the actual names, you can use something like:

```
Dim parentNames = xml.Elements.Select(function(element) element.Name)
```

Note that in each of these cases, you are getting two results.

If you really want to strip out the chidren, you want:

```
Dim parentElements = xml.Elements.Select(function(element) new XElement(element.Name,element.Attributes))
```

Can you extend your question to show what you're really looking for?

Comment: Descendants() method gets all descendants, not just direct descendants. In this case, descendants of "root" would include all Child elements as well.

Comment: @Tormod, you sure? See the example? If not, whats the diff between Descendants and Elements?

Answer (score 20):

[XElement.Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.elements.aspx) gets the collection of child elements.  For example ...

```
var s = @"<root>
             <e1>
                 <e2>
                 </e2>
             </e1>
             <e1>
                 <e2>
                 </e2>
             </e1>
             <e1>
                 <e2>
                 </e2>
             </e1>
          </root>";

var doc = XElement.Load( new StringReader(s) );

Console.WriteLine( doc.Elements().Count() ); // 3
Console.WriteLine( doc.Descendants().Count()); //6
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Linq we can do that.

```
string s = "<Root><Parent id=\"1\"><Child>Thomas</Child></Parent><Parent id=\"2\"><Child>Tim</Child><Child>Jamie</Child></Parent></Root>";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(s);
foreach (XElement DirectChild in xdoc.Descendants().Where(child => child.Parent == xdoc.Root))
{
//Do stuff here
}
```

Hope this helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If all direct descendants have the same known element name, and this element name can't appear in another level, you can use xml.Descendants("Parent").

Answer (score -1):

Why not use XPath?

```
Dim myXML As var = New XmlDocument()
myXML.Load(myXML.xml)

For Each node As XmlNode In myXML.SelectNodes("//")
    Dim myVar As var = node.SelectSingleNode("Parent").InnerText
Next
```

Take this with a pinch of salt - I just converted it from C# to VB.

Comment: XLinq does it quite neatly as is [once one gets over the confision of which method to use :P]

Comment: Fair enough :P
I'll have to look into it, I guess XPath is becoming outdated if you're all moving on to XLinq!