# query deep into xElement using linq-xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I have XML

```
<Envelopes>
  <Envelope   xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <Body>
      <UpdateObjectResponse xmlns="http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS" 
                            CommandID="UpdateObject picklist">
        <RetKey>426358</RetKey>
        <RetType>156</RetType>
      </UpdateObjectResponse>
    </Body>
  </Envelope>                
  <Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <Body>
      <UpdateObjectResponse xmlns="http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS" 
                            CommandID="UpdateObject picklist">
        <RetKey>426358</RetKey>
        <RetType>156</RetType>
      </UpdateObjectResponse>
    </Body>
  </Envelope>
</Envelopes>
```

and  I am trying to get value of `RetKey` element like so

```
var query = from t in xdoc.Descendants("Envelope") select t;

foreach (XElement item in query)
{
    var k = item.Element("Body").Element("UpdateObjectResponse").Element("RetKey").Value;
}
```

var `query` and `item` are getting set properly, but I am getting this error within the `foreach` loop

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: i am not sure what i am doing wrongly, but i have tried to solve this for todays now, this is the best way i can put the question on SO

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see anything obvious that's wrong with your code.

I'll assume you're using VS? Try running the following code with a break point in each line of the foreach and chech the locals at each step, to see which of the .Element(..) queries might be the problem. Check each of the variables in in the **locals view** at each step, to see if something unexpected appears in one of the XElements.

```
var query = from t in xdoc.Descendants("Envelope") select t;
foreach (XElement item in query)
{
    var j = item;
    var k = item.Element("Body");
    var l = k.Element("UpdateObjectResponse");
    var m = l.Element("RetKey");
    var n = m.Value;
}
```

Either you will see which of the variables jklmn is different than expected, or the code will break with a more informative exception.

Note: at least in VS2015, there's a little magnifying glass in the locals view, which lets you nicely view XMLs (in case you didn't know).

**Edit**: I was not aware of the [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226899/linq-to-xml-how-do-i-get-only-direct-descendants-of-an-xelement) between XElement.Descendants and XElement.Elements and I am still unclear on how to do this properly with the cascaded namespaces.
See [Without or only root namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387067.aspx).
See [Strip namespaces from Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145659/ignore-namespaces-in-linq-to-xml) in case the namespace isn't fixed.

I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229679/how-to-query-xelement-with-two-namespaces) might be the solution, though. If I get it correctly, you can just write

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS";
var klist = from t in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "RetKey") select t.Value;
```

to get a list of the RetKey values in that xml. Maybe also try xdoc.Root.Descendants to avoid the first namespace.

Comment: J and K are getting set properly, but l is not , could it be because of the namespace attribute in the updateObjectResponse tag ?

Comment: value for k is <Body>
- <UpdateObjectResponse xmlns="http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS" CommandID="UpdateObject picklist">
  <RetKey>426358</RetKey> 
  <RetType>156</RetType> 
  </UpdateObjectResponse>
  </Body>

Comment: Have you tried what is done  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229679/how-to-query-xelement-with-two-namespaces)? You probably need to use .Descendants again.

Comment: i took off the namesapce in updateObjectResponse element, and it worked, thanks @gMueller